# Why do I sometimes get errors when I try to set the value of a variable in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, variables, syntax

I am having a bit of trouble understanding how variables work in VBA. Sometimes I get errors when I try to put a value into the variable.

For example:

```
Sub test3()
Dim myvar2 As Integer


'Does Not work -- Type Mismatch Error
'myvar2 = [D1:D10]


'Works
'myvar2 = Range("D4")
'myvar2 = Range("D4").Value
'myvar2 = Evaluate("SUM(D1:D10)")

MsgBox (myvar2)

End Sub
```

FYI the values in D1:D10 are all integers, so I don't know why I get that type mismatch error.

Evaluate("SUM(D1:D10)") is equivalent to [D1:D10].. so why does one work and the other doesn't?

I'm obviously just getting into VBA... so maybe this is a rare case.... all my other troubles were because I was trying to use .Value after something that wasn't an object.

I've watched quite a few videos on variables but none of them answer my question.

tl;dr ---

myVar = (what can I put here / not put here to have this value stored as a variable)

Comment: what do you mean "to not have this value stored as a variable"?

Comment: Evaluate("SUM(D1:D10)") is **NOT** equivalent to [D1:D10]

Comment: You want `[SUM(D1:D10)]` which is equivalent to `Evaluate("SUM(D1:D10)") `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `Evaluate("SUM(D1:D10)")` is equivalent to `[D1:D10]`

No, it's not.

`[D1:D10]` is equivalent to `Range("D1:D10")`

So the error is arising because `myVar2` is an `Integer` to which you're assigning a variant array.

The rest of your code "works", so I'm not sure what the actual question is.

```
'Works
myvar2 = Range("D4")
myvar2 = Range("D4").Value
myvar2 = Evaluate("SUM(D1:D10)")

MsgBox (myvar2)
```

Comment: @OligarchicTendencies that's not what any of that means

Comment: @OligarchicTendencies The line which raises the error (`myvar2 = [D1:D10]`) is superfluous. It does not affect the other lines of code, it is not an input to a function, etc., and it is immediately overwritten on the subsequent assignment. Simply remove this line, it's completely unnecessary.

Comment: Yeah, I guess the question is, what can be stored as a variable? --- An entire worksheet? ... I guess i'll just have to experiment. I don't get how a range can be stored as a variable because a range contains many values, is it just like concatenated? or does it then become an array??

Comment: *Anything* can be stored as a variable, but not as an *Integer* :)  To store a worksheet, you `Dim sh As Worksheet` and assign `Set sh = Worksheets("Sheet1")` etc. To store a range of cells, `Dim rng as Range` and then `Set rng = Range("D1:D10")`, etc...  Although VBA doesn't require type declaration, *if* a variable is typed (e.g., `As Integer`) it cannot be treated as a dynamically-typed variable, so you can't later assign it as a `Sheet` or `Range` or `Scripting.FileSystemObject`, etc.

Comment: Yep I know, that's why the other lines are commented out, i was just trying things one by one

Answer (score 1):

OR if you are interested just in the values of those cells, you can store them into an array variable like you said in a comment.

For VBA the Excel Range is two dimensional so if you want to have a one-dimensional array, you'll need to use some other ways than plain assigning a range to a variable.

```
Sub arraytest()

Dim myarr1D(10) As Integer
Dim myarr2D()

For n = 1 To Range("D1:D10").Cells.Count

    myarr1D(n) = Range("D1:D10").Cells(n, 1).Value

Next n

myarr2D = Range("D1:D10")

Debug.Print myarr1D(3)
Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Sum(myarr1D)

Debug.Print myarr2D(3, 1)
Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Sum(myarr2D)

End Sub
```